# Error while creating sql database in existing Azure SQL Server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

While creating a sql database with following parameters:

`Want to use SQL elastic pool? - No
Compute and storage - Free, 32 MB storage`

and default Additional settings using existing Azure SQL Server, an error occurs with 'Conflict' status and status message:

```
"statusMessage": {
  "status": "Failed",
  "error": {
    "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
    "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "InternalServerError",
        "message": "An unexpected error occured while processing the request."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But there was no error while both creating the first database with the same parameters and new SQL server.

Is there any way how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your IP whitelisted and allowed access? Are you allowed to create more than 1 db?

Comment: Yes. But how to find out if i'm allowed to create more than 1 db (p.s. i'm using free trial account)?

Comment: are you using free student account?

Comment: Not, i'm using [Azure free account](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure SQL Database allows you to create one free Azure SQL Server database per region, it reverts to Standard after 365 days. That is what I know ever since you use PowerShell to create it. It may work with REST API or using the portal.

```
New-AzureRmSqlDatabase -DatabaseName $DatabaseName  -ServerName $sqlServer.ServerName 
-ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup.ResourceGroupName -Edition 'Free' 
-RequestedServiceObjectiveName 'Free'
```

Not all regions support it also. This works only for the following regions, for now:

```
 Location           DisplayName
 --------           -------------------
 australiaeast      Australia East
 australiasoutheast Australia Southeast
 centralindia       Central India
 eastasia           East Asia
 francecentral      France Central
 japaneast          Japan East
 japanwest          Japan West
 koreacentral       Korea Central
 koreasouth         Korea South
 northcentralus     North Central US
 northeurope        North Europe
 southeastasia      Southeast Asia
 southindia         South India
 uksouth            UK South
 ukwest             UK West
 westcentralus      West Central US
 westeurope         West Europe
 westindia          West India
 westus2            West US 2
```